# Javascript regex to test a number (integer or decimal, positive or negative ) range

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find out whether a string is a valid range with `-` as a separator. Examples like these should pass the test:

```
1-5
1-10.1
10.5-20.5
-10.5-8
-2--1 << minus two to minus one
-3.5--1
-20.5--2.1
```

The negative to negative range may seem weird without spaces but I'm stuck with that.

Do you think this regex is good enough for the job?

`/(-?[0-9]+[.]*)+-(-?[0-9]+[.]*)+/`

Comment: Does it work for all your use/edge cases? If yes, then yes.

Comment: Is `5-1` supposed to be valid?

Comment: What about "55...555.555-2"?

Comment: No, 5-1 is not valid. Must be the smaller number first. I use it to extract the min and max numbers from the string.

Comment: Well if you're going to put each part through `Number()` or whatever to let that determine the validity and the ordering, then it's probably fine.

Comment: Regex does not perform arithmetic so ensuring the left-side number is smaller than the right side number is impossible with pure regex.

Comment: The `(-?[0-9]+[.]*)+-` part is a bad regex practice. You have two optional patterns inside the group, and the whole pattern boils down to `([0-9]+)+-` that is catastrophic backtracking prone. Avoid such constructs that do not appear at the end of the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex does not perform arithmetic so making sure the left-side number is less than the right side requires additional processing.

You can verify the input is in the correct format and extract the numbers by making use of capture groups:

```
^(-?\d*\.?\d+)-(-?\d*\.?\d+)$
```

- `^` - start of line
- `(` - start capture group

  - `-?` - optional dash (negative)
  - `\d*\.?\d+` - allow floating or whole number
- `)` - end capture group
- `-` - range dash
- `(` - start capture group

  - `-?` - optional dash (negative)
  - `\d*\.?\d+` - allow floating or whole number
- `)` - end capture group
- `$` - end of line

https://regex101.com/r/m6cT2o/1

However, to verify that the first number is smaller than the second number requires additional JS processing.

```js
var rangeRegex = /^(-?\d*\.?\d+)-(-?\d*\.?\d+)$/;
var str = '-10.5-8';

var array = str.match(rangeRegex);

if( array !== null && array[1] < array[2]){
  console.log('good');
}
else{
  console.log('bad');
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: If this approach is acceptable, then there is no need splitting if you add capturing groups to the intial regex. OP can then use the captured values directly for comparison. I'd then use `^(-?\d*\.?\d+)-(-?\d*\.?\d+)$`.